# tinyMCE load content only first time

Tags: jquery, tinymce-4

I dinamically create some textarea using jQuery like the following

```
var editor1 = $("<textarea>").attr("name", "Message1");
$("#div1").append(editor1);
tinymce.init({
    target: editor1,
    plugins: [
        'textcolor searchreplace link image base64image imagetools table hr emoticons'
    ],
    toolbar: [
        'fontselect fontsizeselect forecolor backcolor | cut copy paste | undo redo | searchreplace',
        'bold italic underline strikethrough superscript subscript | removeformat | bullist numlist | outdent indent | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | link unlink | base64image table hr emoticons'
    ],
    menubar: false,
    height: 300
});
```

The editor is inside a jQuery UI modal dialog. After that, I set the editor content in this way

```
 $("textarea[name='Message']").html("some html content");
```

First time I open the dialog and load the content into the editor all works, but If I close the jQuery UI dialog and then I reopen it, the HTML content is not loaded into the editor.

On the jQuery UI dialog close event I remove all editor instances for re-creating them the next time the dialog is opened in order to show the new content.

```
// dialog close event
close: function () {
    tinymce.remove();
}
```

Comment: Please provide your jquery ui code

Comment: Unless you can provide a working example for people to see/play with there won't be a whole lot people can do to assist you.  Please see this SO page on creating a minimal, complete, verifiable example:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve